# Ubuntu install package from specific PPA

Tags: ubuntu

Is there any way on Ubuntu from the command line to specify from which repository to install a certain package?

I need to install a package from our own PPA, which works fine for all the packages we have except that one of them is named "watchdog" and when I try to install it, the watchdog installed is from another PPA and therefore a completely different software.

I was hoping there would be an option to pass to the `apt-get install` command that would allow me to specify from which repo to install but from what I can see in the docs there is no such thing and every google search I did was fruitless.

Any idea how to do this without having to rename our software package?

Comment: Try http://askubuntu.com/questions/27362/how-to-only-install-updates-from-a-specific-repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a version of the software in apt after the package name with an `=` sign. i.e `apt get install watchdog=your.version.number+company-etc`

Comment: Also note that you can view which packages are currently available for install with: apt-cache madison packagename http://askubuntu.com/questions/447/how-can-i-see-all-versions-of-a-package-that-are-available-in-the-archive